# Z score estimation with groupby or condition in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a statistics reference table for rental value as shown below.

```
Sector      Usage     Mean_Rent       Standard_deviation
SE1         R         100             10
SE1         C         120             5
SE2         R         200             50
SE2         C         150             60
```

And also I have tenancy contract table, which contains tenanacy contract information

```
ID     Sector     Usage     Tenancy_year       Rental
1      SE1        R         2020               120
2      SE1        C         2020               180
3      SE1        R         2020               210
4      SE2        R         2020               170
5      SE2        C         2020               190
6      SE2        R         2020               210
```

In the above table, I would like to create a new column Z_score. Where the Z-score is calculated using reference table with the combination of Sector and Usage column in pandas.

Expected Output

```
    ID     Sector     Usage     Tenancy_year       Rental     Z_score
    1      SE1        R         2020               120        (120-100)/10
    2      SE1        C         2020               180        (180-120)/5
    3      SE1        R         2020               210        (210-100)/10
    4      SE2        R         2020               170        (170-200)/50
    5      SE2        C         2020               190        (190-150)/60
    6      SE2        R         2020               210        (210-200)/50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the two tables are `df1` and `df2` (in the order presented), you can `merge` them and then create the z-score:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', on=['Sector', 'Usage'])

df['Z_score'] = (df.Rental - df.Mean_Rent) / df.Standard_deviation
```